# wait for volley response and then return value from function

Tags: android, android-volley, delay

I am using volley library to get response from server
I want that when the response from volley receives then function return the existence `boolean` value, I have tried almost all methods on stack overflow like wait/ notify and others but they stop the whole execution and volley response does not receive after that

```
boolean exsitance= false;

public  boolean checkUserExist(final String id, final String email)
{

  try {
      RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
      JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
      if (id != null)
        jsonBody.put("id", id);
      if (email != null)
        jsonBody.put("email", email);
      final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UrlConstants.checkUserExsist, new Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String response) {
             Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response);
             exsitance = true;

            Toast.makeText(context, "user  exsist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            try {
                if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "user not exsist" + error.networkResponse.statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    exsitance = false;

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
      }) {
         @Override
         public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
         }

         @Override
         public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
             try {
                return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
             }
         }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                Log.d("statuscode_volley", responseString);

            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return exsitance;
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

## Volley runs on a different Thread

Since Volley Request runs on a different Thread you need to know when the Volley request gets completed. Only then you should call the method. 
For this you can create an interface which will notify when the method gets completed.

```
public interface VolleyListener{

    public void requestFinished(boolean exsitance);

}
```

**Implement this method in the Activity override the interface method**

```
YourActivity implements VolleyListener{   

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
         ----- Activity code
  }

  ----------
  @Override
  public void requestFinished(boolean exsitance)
  {
     // Do whatever you want to do
  }

}
```

### How to call interface method from Volley Request?

- Typecast the Volleylistener
- Call `volleyListener.requestFinished(true);` or
  `volleyListener.requestFinished(false);` based on the response from
  Volley.
  **Here is a sample snippet**

  ```
  public  boolean checkUserExist(final String id, final String email)
  {
     ------------------

     VolleyListener volleyListener = (VolleyListener)context;

     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {
      volleyListener.requestFinished(true);
     }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      volleyListener.requestFinished(false);

     -------------------
  }
  ```